# How to restrict node access to nodes based on field value?

Tags: users

Im making simple private message system (no need privatemsg), just node with title, body, and user reference field (entity_reference) for recipient(s). How can I restrict access to node only for node author, and users listed in field?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the [Node Access User Reference](http://drupal.org/project/nodeaccess_userreference) module will do exactly what you want.  It allows you to restrict access to a node based upon a user reference field in that node. It even comes in Drupal 6 and 7 flavors.

From what I can tell though, you want to make sure you use only one node access module for your system, so you may want to look at the [Node Access Module Overview](http://drupal.org/node/270000) to make sure this is the best bet.

Comment: I don't know why I miss the module :) that exactly what I need. Need to use OG module, i hope will be no problems ;)  Thank You very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

However, if you need this to work with OG, you might have some issues.  I wanted to do the same exact thing, and following this guidance, http://www.phase2technology.com/blog/drupal-7-node-access-grants-locks-and-keys/ , decided to use hook_node_access_records() and hook_node_grants().

I have a field, field_draft, that is a boolean.  If it is on, then access is restricted to just group users who have 'view draft content' role in their group.  Furthermore, they can only see the node with this field if it is in the group that they have the permission in.

First, since I want to use permissions on the group level, I use hook_og_permissions to duplicate my site-wide permissions in OG:

```
 /**
  * Implements hook_og_permission().
  */
 function example_og_permission() {
   $permissions = array();
   foreach (example_permission() as $name => $details) {
    $permissions[$name] = array(
      'title' => $details['title'],
      'description' => isset($details['description']) ? $details['description'] : '',
      'default role' => array(OG_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE),
    );
  }
  return $permissions;
}
```

Next, I use og_user_access() to assign the grant to users who have the access draft content permission in their group(s):

```
function example_node_grants($account, $op) {

    // Check OG
    // We check permissions to access the node, for all the groups the user is a
    // member.
    foreach (og_get_entity_groups() as $group_type => $gids) {
      foreach ($gids as $gid) {
        if ($op == 'view' && og_user_access($group_type, $gid, 'access draft content', $account)) {
            $grants['example_draft_view_'.$gid] = array(EXAMPLE_GRANT_ALL);
        }
      }
    }

    return $grants;
}
```

Finally, I create the grant records.  Note that since the field, field_draft, is a custom field, I need to make sure it exists in the node BEFORE I test if it is on or off.

```
function example_node_access_records($node) {

    // We only care about the node if it's been marked draft. If not, it is
    // treated just like any other node and we completely ignore it.
    if (array_key_exists('field_draft', $node)) { // check to see if field_draft exists in this node
        if (array_key_exists('und', $node->field_draft)) { // I guess needed to do this for those nodes with empty values
            if ($node->field_draft['und'][0]['value'] == 1) {

        // Create grants for OG
        foreach (og_get_entity_groups() as $group_type => $gids) {
          foreach ($gids as $gid) {
            $grants[] = array(
                'realm' => 'example_draft_view_'.$gid,
                'gid' => EXAMPLE_GRANT_ALL,
                'grant_view' => 1,
                'grant_update' => 0,
                'grant_delete' => 0,
                'priority' => 0,
            );
          }
        }
      }
   }

        return $grants;
    }
    // Return nothing if the node has not been marked draft.
}
```

And, voila, I now have an architecture which gives group users access to group "draft" content based upon group roles.

Comment: Interesting approach, but unfortunately it is giving: `Notice: Use of undefined constant EXAMPLE_GRANT_ALL - assumed 'EXAMPLE_GRANT_ALL' in example_node_access_records()`